# Comparing two distributions with relation among buckets

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

I want to compare the following distributions with key-percentage.

> dist1 = 200 - 0.1, 201-0.1, 500-0.8

> dist2 = 200 - 0.15, 201 - 0.05, 500 - 0.8

> dist3 = 200 - 0.1, 201-0.05, 500 - 0.85

dist1 is my original distribution. I want to compare it with dist2 , dist3. When I use something like KL divergence, I get KL(dist2,dist1)> KL(dist3,dist1) but in my current use case its the opposite, I want a metric which say dist2 is closer to dist1 than dist3 because there is only change between closer buckets i.e, 200,201 in dist2 compared to dist1 whereas in dist3 there is a movement from 201 bucket to 500 bucket.

Something like mean would work in this case but I want a more rigorous method of comparing these distributions which can capture all the variations.

Thanks